# Получить высоту wrap_content во время создания кастомной Button

Tags: android, android-button

Делаю кастомную градиентную кнопку **программно**.
Имеется такой код:

```
public class MyGradientButton extends AppCompatButton {

    private float mCornerRadius;
    private int mBtnHeight = 100;

    public MyGradientButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setCustomBackground();
    }

    public MyGradientButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomBackground();
    }

    public MyGradientButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setCustomBackground();
    }

    private void setCustomBackground() {
        // Устанавливаем стиль кастомного Drawable
        setBackground(
                generateBackgroundWithShadow()
        );
    }

    /* Получаем Drawable с нужными состояними */
    private Drawable generateBackgroundWithShadow() {

        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_enabled }, chooseDrawableState(2));
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled}, chooseDrawableState(1));
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled }, chooseDrawableState(0));

        return stateListDrawable;
    }

    /* Получаем отдельные Drawable с разными градиентами */
    private Drawable chooseDrawableState(final int state) {
        float[] outerRadius = {
                mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,
                mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,
                mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,
                mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius
        };

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        // Устанавливаем тень кнопки
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShadowLayer(mCornerRadius / 3, 0, 5, mColorShadow);

        /*
         * Выбираем цвета для состояний
         * 0 - normal
         * 1 - pressed
         * 2 - disabled
         */
        switch(state) {
            case 0:
                shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, mBtnHeight, 0, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
                break;
            case 1:
                shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, mBtnHeight, 0, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
                break;
            case 2:
                shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, mBtnHeight, 0, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
                break;
        }

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, shapeDrawable.getPaint());

        shapeDrawable.setShape(new RoundRectShape(outerRadius, null, null));

        LayerDrawable drawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{shapeDrawable});
        drawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 15);

        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Ну и собственно использование кнопки:

```
<com.test.custom.MyGradientButton
    style="@style/GradientButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Вход" />
```

Где стиль обьявлен следующим образом:

```
<style name="GradientButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Проблема заключается в этой строчке:

```
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, mBtnHeight, 0, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

Во время создания Drawable с применением градиента необходимо указать точку y0 с которой начинается рисование градиента, в моем случае **y0 = mBtnHeight**. Но возникает вопрос **как получить и применить высоту** которая указана как **wrap_content** в xml?

Comment: Вам нужно изменить подход в реализации. В момент вызова конструктора никто не знает будущую высоту элемента. Только после того как контейнер распределит элемент внутри себя, getHeight() вернет правильную высоту, до этого там будет 0.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, а как посоветуете в данном случае поступить? Только что пробовал проводить инициализацию в методах `onSizeChanged` и `onLayout`, а не в конструкторе. Так в принципе все ок. Но я не уверен что это правильное решение... Тем более у меня перерисовка происходит 2 раза. Первый раз высота устанавливается в 96dp (стиль родителя), второй в 133dp (кастомный стиль).

Comment: Судя по документации: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View , правильные места `onMeasure` или `onSizeChanged`, `onLayout` актуально для контейнеров.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, т.е. по сути вариант инициализации `initBackground();` в `onSizeChanged` не является плохим?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja а Вы в начале сказали что необходимо изменить подход в реализации, а что посоветуете изменить?

Comment: Вот именно момент создания фона и предлагал изменить. Может еще чего на ваше усмотрение исходя из этого. Переименуйте `initBackground()` в `setCustomBackground` и будет код лучше читаться. `init` чего угодно обычно присходит в начале и один раз.

Comment: Раз у вас уже созданный фон нельзя переиспользовать под другой размер, то да, в `onSizeChanged` будет Ок.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, я тоже очень хочу попытаться изменить логику создания фона, но пока не хватает знаний как это сделать. Хотелось бы что бы была возможность инициализировать это дело в конструкторе и все. Можете пожалуйста помочь в этом? P.S. Названия метода переименовал.

Comment: Посмотрите как градиент создавать через разметку вместо кода: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, это я знаю, спасибо. У меня с самого начала был описан xml с состояними, но я не могу его нормально интегрировать в код. Если его использовать, то не отображается нижняя тень (точнее, xml перекрывает всю поверхность), в ней вот вся суть.